# mysql query optimization where vs inner join

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I have a query that takes forever.

I can't find a way to make it faster.
I looked on internet for optimization tricks but didn't find anythig that would make this faster.

Maybe, fresh eyes see something that I didn't :)

Here is the query:

```
Select *,  sum(collection) as tot

 from
(
    SELECT  PHYS.PHYS_ID,
        month(PMT.DT_PD) as Month,
        year(PMT.DT_PD) as Year,
        PRAC.LOC_ID,
        sum(ABS(PMT.PMT_AMT)) as collection         

    FROM
        IDR_ENC ENC,
        IDR_PHYS_PT_XREF PHY_PT,
        IDR_PRACT_LOC PRAC,
        IDR_PMT PMT,
        IDR_PHYS PHYS,
        IDR_CHGS CHG

    where
        ENC.PT_ID      = PHY_PT.PT_ID AND
        ENC.ENC_LOC    = PRAC.LOC_ID  AND
        PHY_PT.PHYS_ID = PHYS.PHYS_ID AND
        PHY_PT.PT_ID   = CHG.PT_ID    AND   
        PMT.CHG_ID     = CHG.CHG_ID   AND              
        DATE_FORMAT(PMT.DT_PD, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-01' and 
        DATE_FORMAT(PMT.DT_PD, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2014-03-31'  and
        PRAC.LOC_ID IN (SELECT LOC_ID FROM IDR_PRACT_LOC WHERE LOC_ID != 0) AND
        PHYS.PHYS_ID in (SELECT PHYS_ID FROM IDR_PHYS WHERE PHYS_ID != 0) AND
        PMT.TRN_TYP NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'R', 'T') AND
        CHG.CPT4_CD NOT LIKE 'J%'

    GROUP BY PHYS.PHYS_ID,  month(PMT.DT_PD),year(PMT.DT_PD) 

)TOT_COLL 

group by month,year
```

Comment: Does this query really run? GROUP BY in the inner query doesn't contain PRAC.LOC_ID

Comment: @Multisync, MySQL is not strict about that by default. It does mean that PRAC.LOC_ID takes an arbitrary value from the group of rows. It's up to the developer to fashion the query to ensure against this.

Answer (score 1):

1. GROUP BY in the inner query doesn't contain PRAC.LOC_ID
2. if it's the whole query then you can get the desired result in the inner query
3. You call date_format "too often", it's better to convert '2014-01-01' and '2014-03-31' to a date (+indexes on this column, if any, would work)
4. PHYS.PHYS_ID in (SELECT PHYS_ID FROM IDR_PHYS WHERE PHYS_ID != 0) must be replaced with PHYS.PHYS_ID != 0
5. PRAC.LOC_ID IN (SELECT LOC_ID FROM IDR_PRACT_LOC WHERE LOC_ID != 0) must be replaced with PRAC.LOC_ID != 0